# SublimeText3 / Python - color theme (fg/bg) for class not working

Tags: python, themes, sublimetext3

I am on OSX El Capitan. I have the following in my .tmTheme

```
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>Class name</string>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>entity.name.class</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#99FF99</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Why isn't `foo` in the following python code colored #99FF99?

```
class foo(bar):
    def __init__(self):
        bar.__init__(self)
        print "foo"
```

Am I looking at the wrong thing in `entity.name.class`? Is this related to El Capitan in any way?

Answer (score 0):

The code above was created by and downloaded from http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/. I tried a couple of variants and scope `entity.name.type.class` appears to be the right scope instead of `entity.name.class` for my version of ST3.